# Check if text input is empty if so dont convert to float

Tags: ruby, validation, methods, sinatra

I am writing a small ruby app using sinatra and have a text input for input that I then convert to a flat using the `.to_f` method. However if the input is empty the `.to_f` still converts the empty string to a 0 value.

I would like it to be checked so if the input is blank/empty it does not attempt to convert it to a number.
Below is the code I have so far, I have tried adding `.empty?` to the end but it throws a method error.

```
weight = Weight.create(
    :amount => params[:amount].to_f,
    :user_id => current_user.id,
    :created_at => Time.now
)
```

Comment: instead of the 0 value, what would you like to get from an empty input?

Comment: Well I guess nil then I would hope Datamapper would pick up on this as it has a presence validation on it. So Im hoping ti would throw and error.

Comment: `:amount => params[:amount].to_s.empty? ? nil : params[:amount].to_f,` should make sense. `to_s` eliminates the test on nil value, 'cause `nil.to_s` yields empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two basic options.  The first is to use the ternary operator, and give a default value when the string is empty.  The basic template is:

```
(params[:amount].empty?) ? <EMPTY EXPRESSION> : <NOT EMPTY EXPRESSION>
```

For example, to return `nil` when `params[:amount]` is empty:

```
weight = Weight.create(
    :amount => (params[:amount].empty?) ? nil : params[:amount].to_f,
    :user_id => current_user.id,
    :created_at => Time.now
)
```

The second is to use Ruby's logical operators.  The basic template is:

```
params[:amount].empty? && <EMPTY EXPRESSION> || <NOT EMPTY EXPRESSION>
```

For example, to raise an exception when `params[:amount]` is empty:

```
weight = Weight.create(
    :amount => params[:amount].empty? && \
        (raise ArgumentError.new('Bad :amount')) || params[:amount].to_f
    :user_id => current_user.id,
    :created_at => Time.now
)
```

Both ways can return `nil` or raise the exception.  The choice is largely stylistic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more Java/EE way of doing things than is stricly necessary, but I find that parameter validation is such a common thing that it helps to define the functionality in one place and then just reuse it.

```
class ParamsExtractor
  def get_float_parameter(params,key)
    params[key] && !(params[key].nil? || params[key].to_s.strip == '') ? params[key].to_f : 0.0
  end
end

weight = Weight.create(
  :amount => ParamsExtractor.get_float_parameter(params, :amount),
  :user_id => current_user.id,
  :created_at => Time.now
)
```

There are additional things you can do (modules etc) but this is clear and easilly testable via RSpec

Answer (score 0):

```
x = '' => ""
x.to_f unless x.empty? => nil
x = '1' => "1"
x.to_f unless x.empty? => 1.0
```